# iOS App to Ping Users Like Find My iphone "Play a Sound"

Tags: ios

I have an idea for an app and have the design created but unsure how to go about doing it programatically.  The idea is simple... ping a silent phone the way "Find My Phone" can make a silent phone make a sound.  The idea is to have the app read an incoming text message with a command embedded in the text from an "authorized" user.

Example: #URGENT from my ***wife*** would make my phone sound even if it was on silent but #URGENT from my **friend** would not cause any action because he is not "Authorized" in my app.

From what I have found online, reading text messages in iOS is prohibited unless you build your own API/SKD (BMW reads the text from the notification center for their iDrive function) which will then get rejected by the app store.  Is this correct or is there a way to do this?

My questions:

1. Can an app trigger an event by reading text messages with embedded commands like on Android?
2. In iOS is there any way to make a silent phone create a sound at full volume?

I've found that this is possible for Android, but I want to see if it is possible for iOS.

Comment: Are you asking this question for both operating systems, or just iOS?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for iOS capability.  I know it is possible on Android already, those links were just for reference.  Any ideas about iOS and if this is possible?

Comment: Right, the links to Android apps, and the mention of Android, was a bit confusing. No, I don't develop for either platform, just want to help make it clearer.

Comment: An iOS app must be able to attach to an SMS received event - presumably the stock iOS text messaging app can be replaced? If so, other apps must do this in order to show the 'new message' icon.

Comment: iOS essentially allows no interaction with the SMS system. You'd have to do this with your own messaging server sending push notifications to the receiving phone.

Comment: @halfer: Nope. Apple doesn't allow you to change or hook *anything*. They only just allowed custom keyboards and sharing options.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer is **no**.

In order:

1. An iOS app has no access to the text messages of the user at all, so there's no way to trigger anything that way.
2. Not as a notification sound, but it's possible that by using a background audio session you could play a sound on a phone that is *silenced*, but still has the media volume up. However, Apple might not like this (you'd be using media playback APIs for alert noises, Apple doesn't want anyone circumventing the users decision to silence the phone).